# Is there a way to check if a lazy-loaded component (with React.Lazy) has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense, react-lazy-load

I'm working on an app where we have transitions between pages that we want to delay if the next page has any lazy-loaded components that haven't been loaded yet. So I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to reliably check whether a lazy-loaded component has finished loading yet.

This solution works, but *only* the first time the lazy-loaded component tries to load -- i.e. not if it renders instantly because the lazy-loaded component is already loaded.

```
import React, {PropsWithChildren, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function SuspenseTrigger(props) {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={
      <>
        {props.fallback}
        <Trigger onLoad={props.onLoad} onComplete={props.onComplete} />
      </>
    }>
      {props.children}
    </React.Suspense>
  )
}

function Trigger(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.onLoad) {
      props.onLoad()
    }

    return () => {
      if (props.onComplete) {
        setTimeout(props.onComplete)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return <></>
}
```

This component correctly calls `onLoad` and `onComplete` the first time it's loaded. However, on subsequent times, because the lazy-loaded component is now cached, the children are rendered instantly and **the fallback is never rendered, which means `onLoad` and `onComplete` never get called.**

One thing I've tried is putting a second `Trigger` inside the body of the `SuspenseTrigger`:

```
function ensureLoadCompleteCalled() {
  onLoad()
  onComplete()
}

return (
  <React.Suspense fallback={/* same as before */}>
    {props.children}
    <Trigger onLoad={ensureLoadCompleteCalled} />
  </React.Suspense>
)
```

**That doesn't work because the children of `Suspense` get rendered instantly even when other elements aren't fully loaded.** So `onLoad` and `onComplete` get called instantly, regardless of whether the Suspense is finished loading or not.

To get around that, I've also tried some fancier state-checking [(code on PasteBin)](https://pastebin.com/psqVSdT9). The main tough thing there is checking whether the fallback has been rendered which I can't figure out how to reliably do. I've tried waiting 100 ms before checking but even that doesn't work reliably for some reason. Maybe it's possible with `useRef`?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a second trigger with the children, like this? `{props.children}<Trigger onLoad={props.onComplete} />`

Answer (score 2):

have you try wrapping your `{props.children}` on a Loader Functional Component, so on useLayoutEffect yo execute the onComplete function?

Here just a raw idea, but it may work...

```js
const Loader = ({ onLoad, onComplete, children }) => {
  if (onLoad) {
    onLoad();
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (onComplete) {
      onComplete();
    }
  }, []);

  return children;
}
```

```js
<React.Suspense fallback={/* same as before */}>
    <Loader onLoad={onLoad} onComplete={onComplete}>
      {props.children}
    </Loader>
</React.Suspense>
```

Comment: I keep getting this
Warning: Cannot update a component (`BaseRoutes`) while rendering a different component (`Loader`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Loader`, follow the stack trace as described in
    in Loader (at BaseRoutes.js:81)
    in Suspense (at BaseRoutes.js:80)
    in Switch (at BaseRoutes.js:74)
    in BaseRoutes (at Layout.js:55)
    in Layout (at App.js:21)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:20)
    in App (at src/index.js:55)

Answer (score 0):

Would checking `_status` work?

```
const Uninitialized = -1;
const Pending = 0;
const Resolved = 1;
const Rejected = 2;
```

See https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactLazy.js